# qt application deploy (compatibility)

Tags: qt, packaging

I have ported on Linux a QT application that I developed under Windows. I have Ubuntu 18.10 and QT library 5.12, (I don't need these specific version, but that's what I found at the time of my download).

Now I want to distribute this application to a few of my friends, but I don't want them to download the full QT suite and compile source code. I'd like to build a "regular" package that they can install. After giving up with 'Snapcraft', I'm trying to use 'Debreate', but there's something I don't understand about dependencies.

I'd like my application to be installable on Ubuntu versions different from mine and I'd like the installer to install required QT dependencies without installing the huge QT world.

How can I rely that any distribution finds QT libraries version 5.12? Can I indicate a ppa to be added?
Also including required .so files in the package has failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest option to do is develop an AppImage.

https://wiki.qt.io/Deploying_a_Qt5_Application_Linux

> Creating a standalone application bundle
>
> Deploying a Qt5 application for Linux as a standalone bundle involves
>   bundling it with the necessary Qt components that are needed for the
>   application to run. These can be Qt libraries, Qt plugins, and
>   especially the Qt platform plugin.
>
> A deployment tool is available that automates the prodecures described
>   here and provide an AppImage

Link to deployment tool: https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt

Comment: thank you for your reply. I already know this tool but I got discouraged because it only works on the oldest still supported LTS version of Ubunu. In lack of other hints, I will insist on that tool

Comment: Hey, but that's a good thing, because of this: "We recommend to target the oldest still-supported Ubuntu LTS release and build your applications on that. If you do this, the resulting binaries should be able to run on newer (but not older) systems (Ubuntu and other distributions)." So what this means is that if you build your AppImage on an older Ubuntu system, that should run on newer and the newest distro. Create a VM and take it from there.

Comment: A little complicated to use a VM just for this in my opinion... Would the options `-unsupported-bundle-everything -unsupported-allow-new-glibc` work on newer distributions?